# AS2: How do you remove onEnterFrame?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

For the life of me, I can't get this event to stop. I originally wrote this code in AS3, but when my project manager gave me the specs, they wanted it in AS2. Not really a big deal, most of the code just needed some tweaks.

However, in this one part, I play a small part of a movieclip backward (as an exit animation, opposite of its intro animation). In AS3, it went smoothly like this:

```
function playExit() {
     this.gotoAndStop(MovieClip(root).exitLabel);
     this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playBackwards);
}
function playBackwards(e:Event) {
     this.prevFrame();
     if(this.currentFrame == 1) {
          this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playBackwards);
          finishExit();
     }
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert it to AS2. It seems like it *should* work like this:

```
function playExit() {
     this.gotoAndStop(_root.exitLabel);
     this.onEnterFrame = function() {
          playBackwards();
     }
}
function playBackwards() {
     trace('Backwaaaaaaaaards, woooo!!');
     this.prevFrame();
     if(this.currentFrame == 1) {
          delete this.onEnterFrame;
          trace('Backwards Completed.');
          finishExit();
     }
}
```

However, it seems like my little happy backwards trace statement is still running (thus not being deleted) even after my "Backwards Completed." shows up in the output. So when the animation loops, it doesn't even show up at all because it's still trying to run backwards. There's no compiling errors, and I'm not getting any other errors. Am I missing something?

The publish settings are set for Flash Player 8, AS2.

Please and thank you.

Edit: I event tried it like this because I thought it may have been a scope issue, but it only made it worse because it didn't even play backwards (movieclip stayed on the stage).

```
function playExit() {
     this.gotoAndStop(_root.exitLabel);
     this.onEnterFrame = function() {
          trace('Backwaaaaaaaaards, woooo!!');
          this.prevFrame();
          if(this.currentFrame == 1) {
               delete this.onEnterFrame;
               trace('Backwards Completed.');
               finishExit();
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. This always happens after I post the question.

Turns out that the "Backwards Completed." never pulled up in my Output (I ran ctrl F to find it, and it wasn't there, it was a different trace statement that led me to believe it showed up).

Anyway, I forgot to change

```
this.currentFrame
```

to

```
this._currentFrame
```

Thanks again, guys.

Comment: typo here - this._currentframe (with small f)

Comment: No, it's correct as is with the capital F. "currentframe" is not a keyword; it is case sensitive. Thank you, though.

Comment: No, you are wrong. In AC2 right one is _currentframe. currentFrame is AC3 property.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I typed in _currentframe and it didn't turn blue, as if Flash didn't recognize it where _currentFrame did. It works with _currentFrame too, so I'm not going to fix what isn't broken. I'm not sure why it works, but it just does. Thank you for your insight. But I see what you mean in the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001287.html

Comment: It's AC2 magic. Sometimes something that shouldn't - work. Sometimes something that definitely should - won't)